# Is there a way to set Sound Balance permanently for MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, audio

My left speaker of Macbook pro is producing a bit muffled sound. So I have turned the Sound Balance setting in System Preferences towards midway through right speaker, and it's no longer noticeable.

However, this goes off every time system restarts and I've to move the slider to right again. Is there a way to set this permanently (via terminal maybe?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had the same problem and resolved it.

Issue the following commands.

```
$ mv /Library/Preferences/com.apple.soundpref.plist /Library/Preferences/com.apple.soundpref.plist.backup

$ mv /Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.DeviceSettings.plist /Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.DeviceSettings.plist.backup

$ mv /Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.SystemSettings.plist /Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.SystemSettings.plist.backup
```

Then select whatever preference of sound settings you want and restart the MacBook.

Comment: `com.apple.soundpref.plist` was missing in my system, but renaming the other two files did the job. Thanks!